# Can I query from Dependent model in Django graphene Dynamically?

Tags: django, graphql, django-filter, graphene-python, graphene-django

I have a model like

```
class Project(models.Model):
    status = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class Goal(models.Model):
    goal_id = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True, default="default")
    status = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Issue(models.Model):
    issue_id = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True, default="default")
    status = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    goal = models.ForeignKey(
        Goal, null=True, blank=True,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    project = models.ForeignKey(
        Project, null=True, blank=True,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )

class Task(BaseEntityBasicAbstract):
    task_id = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    goal = models.ForeignKey(
        Goal, null=True, blank=True,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    project = models.ForeignKey(
        Project, null=True, blank=True,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
```

Can I write a Dynamic Query function where I can filter the status of the dependent model dynamically?
Like where I can apply join operation from provided arguments.

```
def DynamicQuery(Module, Model, status, dependentModel, dependentModelID):
.
.
.

DynamicQuery(App, Goal, "Open", Project, 1)
```